# Интересная задача

Tags: орфография

Маленький Даня недавно начал говорить и в некоторых словах меняет местами согласные звуки, с которых начинаются второй и третий слоги, например вместо молоко говорит моколо. Какое из слов в Данином произношении будет звучать так же, как правильно произнесённое другое слово русского языка? 
(А) полететь
(Б) полежать
(В) покатать
(Г) подарок
(Д) перелить
Вроде бы несложное задание, правильными будут ответы Б и В, хотя ответ нужно выбрать только один. Что скажете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Вроде бы несложное задание, правильными будут ответы Б и В, хотя ответ
>   нужно выбрать только один. Что скажете?

Правильный ответ: **(В) покатать.**

**P.S.**

Вариант (Б) не проходит:

по[**л'**]ежать  -- мягкий звук

поже[**л**]ать -- твёрдый звук

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Б "правильнее" ответа В, поскольку в нём сохраняется совершенный вид глагола (полежать/пожелать).

Comment: А чем это "правильнее"?